# ruby on rails use variable in association call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, view, associations, render

i have a helper function which renders a partial and i pass a variable called method with it into the view...

when in view i use

```
<%= friend.method.profile.picture %>
```

the method variable can be either **user** or **friend**

and i get

```
wrong number of arguments(0 for 1)
```

i suppose there is a problem how i use the variable being passed into the association call... maybe i have to escape it somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand what you want, you are trying to dynamically call a function based on the value of a string argument called 'method'. Also, 'method' is an existing function in Ruby, (hence your error message about 'wrong number of args' vs 'undefined method'), so I would recommend renaming it in your code.

TLDR:

1. Rename your variable something like "**person**" (instead of 'method'), then
2. try some meta-programming to call the function using send:

   `friend.send(person).profile.picture`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the same answer as ~AmirRubin, but fleshed out more.

I am assuming that friend was the object, method was the helper, .profile is the method you want the helper to use.

Define your helper as:

```
def call_method(object, method_name)
  object.send(method_name)
end
```

In your view call it as:

```
<%= call_method(friend, :profile).picture %>
```

Adjust this if my assumptions are wrong.  If you need to send the method name (symbol) to the partial pass it in the locals.